# Python matplotlib subplots, why is all of the data going to one of the subplots and the other is empty?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two data sets:

short_data_test.csv:

```
Item,Current,Forecast
Test1,19.7,49.7
Test2,6.94,12.4
Test3,0.4147,3.1
Test4,27.9,74.03
```

And short_data_interest_test.csv

```
Item,Current,Forecast
Test1,0,8.8
Test2,0,7.6
Test3,0,33.5
Test4,0,17.65
```

When I plot them in two subplots, the output looks like this:

[image]

You can see that all of the data, and the labels, are in the second, plot and only the points are in the first plot. Why is all of the data, and labels, only appearing on the second plot and not the first? Can someone show me how to edit the code to fix this? This is the code:

```
from matplotlib.pylab import plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import numpy as np

# Import Data
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("short_data_test.csv",sep=',')

left_label = [str(c) + ', '+ str(round(y)) for c, y in zip(df['Item'], df['Current'])]
right_label = [str(c) + ', '+ str(round(y)) for c, y in zip(df['Item'], df['Forecast'])]
klass = ['red' if (y1-y2) < 0 else 'green' for y1, y2 in zip(df['Current'], df['Forecast'])]



# draw line
def newline(p1, p2, color='black'):
    ax1 = plt.gca()
    l = mlines.Line2D([p1[0],p2[0]], [p1[1],p2[1]], color='red' if p2[1] > 70000 else 'green', marker='o', markersize=6)
    ax1.add_line(l)
    return l

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(14,14), dpi= 80)

# Vertical Lines
ax1.vlines(x=1, ymin=0, ymax=75, color='black', alpha=0.7, linewidth=1, linestyles='dotted')
ax1.vlines(x=3, ymin=0, ymax=75, color='black', alpha=0.7, linewidth=1, linestyles='dotted')

# Points
ax1.scatter(y=df['Current'], x=np.repeat(1, df.shape[0]), s=10, color='black', alpha=0.7)
ax1.scatter(y=df['Forecast'], x=np.repeat(3, df.shape[0]), s=10, color='black', alpha=0.7)

# Line Segmentsand Annotation
for p1, p2, c in zip(df['Current'], df['Forecast'], df['Item']):
    newline([1,p1], [3,p2])
    ax1.text(1-0.05, p1, c, horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='center', fontdict={'size':14})
    ax1.text(3+0.05, p2, c, horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='center', fontdict={'size':14})


ax1.text(1-0.05, 75, 'BEFORE',horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='center',fontdict={'size':0.001, 'weight':700})
ax1.text(3+0.05, 75, 'AFTER',horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='center', fontdict={'size':0.0001, 'weight':700})


# Decoration
ax1.set_title("Comparison1", fontdict={'size':18},weight='bold')
ax1.set(xlim=(0,4))
plt.ylabel('Rate1',fontsize=14,weight='bold')
ax1.set_xticks([1,3])
plt.tick_params(labelsize=14)
ax1.set_xticklabels(["Time1", "Time2"],weight='bold')





df2 = pd.read_csv("short_data_interest_test.csv",sep=',')

left_label2 = [str(c) + ', '+ str(round(y)) for c, y in zip(df2['Item'], df2['Current'])]
right_label2 = [str(c) + ', '+ str(round(y)) for c, y in zip(df2['Item'], df2['Forecast'])]
klass2 = ['red' if (y1-y2) < 0 else 'green' for y1, y2 in zip(df2['Current'], df2['Forecast'])]



# draw line
def newline(p1, p2, color='black'):
    ax2 = plt.gca()
    l2 = mlines.Line2D([p1[0],p2[0]], [p1[1],p2[1]], color='red' if p2[1] > 70000 else 'green', marker='o', markersize=6)
    ax2.add_line(l2)
    return l2


# Vertical Lines
ax2.vlines(x=1, ymin=0, ymax=75, color='black', alpha=0.7, linewidth=1, linestyles='dotted')
ax2.vlines(x=3, ymin=0, ymax=75, color='black', alpha=0.7, linewidth=1, linestyles='dotted')

# Points
ax2.scatter(y=df2['Current'], x=np.repeat(1, df2.shape[0]), s=10, color='black', alpha=0.7)
ax2.scatter(y=df2['Forecast'], x=np.repeat(3, df2.shape[0]), s=10, color='black', alpha=0.7)

# Line Segmentsand Annotation
for p1, p2, c in zip(df2['Current'], df2['Forecast'], df2['Item']):
    newline([1,p1], [3,p2])
    ax2.text(1-0.05, p1, c, horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='center', fontdict={'size':14})
    ax2.text(3+0.05, p2, c, horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='center', fontdict={'size':14})


ax2.text(1-0.05, 75, 'BEFORE',horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='center',fontdict={'size':0.001, 'weight':700})
ax2.text(3+0.05, 75, 'AFTER',horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='center', fontdict={'size':0.0001, 'weight':700})


# Decoration
ax2.set_title("Comparison2", fontdict={'size':18},weight='bold')
ax2.set(xlim=(0,4))
plt.ylabel('Rate2',fontsize=14,weight='bold')
ax2.set_xticks([1,3])
plt.tick_params(labelsize=14)
ax2.set_xticklabels(["Time1", "Time2"],weight='bold')



plt.show()
plt.savefig('slopechart.png')
```

Comment: After you create the figure and axes using `fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(…)`, `ax2` will be the current axes. So in your `newline` functions remove `plt.gca()` and simply pass in `ax1` or `ax2`

Comment: pls see a tutorial [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html) on `artist `, it will help you a lot